# What happened to the index of a list when elements are add/removed?

Tags: c#

I've a list of strings **Dad**, **mam**, **Junior**, **Richard**. Let's say, I remove Junior whose index is **2** from the list. Is richard's index becomes 2 or is still 3 with a gap at the second position?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No gap. If you want a gap replace the value at that position with `null` yourself.

Mostly you don't want a gap, so you can be happy that it's kept tidy for you.

One practical consequence though, is that if you are going to be removing **a lot** of items in the same operation, you may find it faster to build a new list with only those you aren't removing (because it moves things around internally after each remove).

It has to be a lot for that to be worth while though. Bear it in mind if you hit a big delay, rather than jumping straight into taking that approach first thing.

Comment: Good to know that a null element can keep help keep indexes the way they were.

Comment: If you want to keep the gaps, you might consider using an array rather than a list. As a rule I'd encourage list to be used over array in most cases (you don't need to know how large it needs to be, for example), but this sounds more "array-ish" than "list-ish".

Comment: The number of objects in the list is not know in advance because it depends on the number of rows coming from the database. it can be 0 or many

Comment: Also I want those gaps because each row has many properties. if the user decides just to clear everything, I just remove the object and replace it with a new one at the same place.

Answer (score 5):

> Let's say, I remove Junior whose index is 2 from the list. Is richard's index becomes 2 or is still 3 with a gap at the second position?

It becomes 2. There are no gaps. And when you add an element this element is appended to the end of the list.

And by the way, come on dude, is it so hard to verify this? I mean you don't have access to a compiler or something?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new[] { "Dad", "mam", "Junior", "Richard" }.ToList();
        list.RemoveAt(2);
        Console.WriteLine(list[2]);
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Richard
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no gap - the edited list only contains three items, and they have indexes of `0`, `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 2):

A regular `List<T>` is not a sorted list.

If you add things on to the end using [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx), current items remain where they are and new items are added to the end of the list.  Current items index do not change.

If you use [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) to insert an item in the middle of the list, indices will shift up past the insertion point.

Similarly, if you [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e) an item, the index of list elements above that item will shift down.

*There will never be a gap in index numbering.  The index will always start at 0 and go up to one less than the length of the list.*

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [Remove method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx), then yes, Richard's index becomes 2. The element you remove is literally removed from the List, and so the indexes will be updated.

If you use the [Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the item is appended to the end of the List, and so all the other elements' indexes are unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

It will become 2. The index of a List is always the position of the item in the list; there can and will never be gaps. Additionally, `Count` will always return the number of items in the list and the indexes of the items will always be 0 to `Count-1`.