# removing values in List<> at index position without decreasing the list size

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an array of structs and add/remove items from it. Tried to transform it into a List, delete the item at the given index WITH the position itself.
 If I use the RemoveAt(index) method for the list, it decreases my list size with one position. The final array should have the same size as in the beginning.

```
struct Cities
{
    public string name;

    public int inhabitansNumber;
}
Cities[] cities = new Cities[500]; // the struct array holding the cities
int i = 0;


//insert items into the array:
if (cities[i].Equals(default(Cities)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the city name:");
    cities[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter population:");
    cities[i].inhabitansNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Values added successfuly!");
    i++;
}


//remove values from the array:
Console.WriteLine("number of element BEFORE deleting in array {0}", cities.Count());
Console.WriteLine("please enter the position of the element that you want to delete:");
int numToRemove = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
List<Cities> citiesToList = cities.ToList();
citiesToList.RemoveAt(numToRemove);
cities = citiesToList.ToArray();
Console.WriteLine("number of element AFTER deleting in array {0}", cities.Count());
```

Comment: Maybe you don't want to remove the item but set it to `null`?

Comment: Kind of depends on what you mean by "size". A `List` has a `Count` and a `Capacity`. Capacity doesn't change if you remove an item, but count will. Capacity will change if you add to the list, and the internal buffer isn't large enough to hold current values + 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happened to the index of a list when elements are add/removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957011/what-happened-to-the-index-of-a-list-when-elements-are-add-removed)

Comment: define what you mean by remove

Comment: The point of using a `List` instead of an `array` is that implementation details of the underlying array are handled without you having to worry.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate question. That user asked what happens with the index when you're removing elements, not what happens with the sixe of the list.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, it would be the best to set the item on the specified index to `null` instead of completely removing the item.

```
myArray[itemIndex] = null;
```

Because you're using structs this isn't possible. But maybe you could declare the array as nullable. So just change

```
Cities[] cities = new Cities[500];
```

to the following

```
Cities?[] cities = new Cities?[500];
```

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. Indeed I thought making it nullable, but I did not know how to put null values in it.

Comment: @PopaAlin: No problem. I'm happy to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your array/list with the element type as nullable:

```
Cities?[] cities = new Cities?[500];
List<Cities?> citiesToList = cities.ToList();
```

If you don't want to make the array nullable, you can change only the list by:

```
List<Cities?> citiesToList = cities.Cast<Cities?>.ToList();
```

You can then use the list indexer and set element to null:

```
citiesToList[numToRemove] = null;
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately my items in the list are of type struct and cannot be nullable :)

Comment: @PopaAlin so, what do you mean by remove?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using only a `for` loop. Hope it will help you also **:)** :

```
//removing item from array without deleting the position
Console.WriteLine("number of element BEFORE deleting in array {0}", cities.Count());
Console.WriteLine("please enter the position of the element that you want to delete:");
int numToRemove = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for (int j = 0; j < cities.Length-1; j++)
{
    if (j >= numToRemove)
    {
        cities[j] = cities[j + 1];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("number of element AFTER deleting in array {0}", cities.Count());
```

Comment: So, what happens when you remove two or more items?

Comment: If you remove one or more items, the array's size will remain the same. Only the elements will be removed.
On the other hand, if you transform it in a list, remove an element then transform it back to array, it will decrease the array size.

Comment: An array is a sequence of elements. A `List` is a sequence of items. If you **remove** either an element or an item the array or list will be shorter. Your solution doesn't alter the array or `List` in any way, it simply **masks** one of the elements or items.